# SetAdded and SetModified can only be called on DataRows with Unchanged DataRowState

Tags: c#, vb.net, datatable

I am trying to update the *RowState* of a DataTable rows to *Added* as it is required for inserting data using DbDataAdapter Update method in database.
In my scenario, I am doing some modification in data of few rows of the DataTable which is changing its RowState to Modified.

Below is the function in VB.Net which I am using to change the RowState

```
Protected Sub SetRowAdded(ByVal DataTable As DataTable)
        For Each row As DataRow In DataTable.Rows
            If Not row.RowState = DataRowState.Added Then row.SetAdded()
        Next
End Sub
```

Because of the aforementioned scenario, I am getting below error while changing RowState

> SetAdded and SetModified can only be called on DataRows with Unchanged
>   DataRowState

Does anyone have any idea that how to get it fixed?

Comment: Where did the data come from in the first place?  Did you populate the `DataTable` by calling `Fill` on a data adapter?  If so, simply set the adapter's `AcceptChangesOnFill` to `False` and then all `RowState` properties will be `Added` from the outset.  You can then make any changes you like to the data without affecting the `RowState` values.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, that can also work as I am filling DataTable using DataAdapter but it my codebase it could impact plethora of other code. Therefore, I will go with DataTable.AcceptChanges() which I can simply use in my method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By doing some research, I am able to find out the answer myself.

The row state of *DataTable* can be changed to *Unchanged* by accepting all the modifications using **DataTable.AcceptChanges()** method. I have changed my code as shown below and it is working absolutely fine now.

```
Protected Sub SetRowAdded(ByVal DataTable As DataTable)
        'Accept pending changes, as only Unchanged rows can be changed to Added or Modified
        DataTable.AcceptChanges()

        For Each row As DataRow In DataTable.Rows
            If Not row.RowState = DataRowState.Added Then row.SetAdded()
        Next
 End Sub
```